# How do I put subscripts in an equation?

Tags: support

I was trying to figure out how to put subscripts into an equation for an answer to a question on Worldbuilding Stackexchange but I don't know how to make subscripts in the equation.  How do I put subscripts into the equation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/607/how-do-i-add-mathematical-notation-using-latex-mathjax - at least, it's answered there.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using $\LaTeX$, just use
`_{}`, putting the thing you want to put in subscript in brackets.

If you're using regular text, use `<sub>` and`</sub>` to surround the text.